# BufferedImage: Performance of fillRect / drawImage with transparent color / image

Tags: java, performance, swing

I found a performance bottleneck and I don't know how to solve it.

**Introduction:** I wrote a sub class of JComponent which paints images in a 50 to 50 grid. Each image has the size of 50 to 50 pixel. The performance of "paintComponent" becomes quite bad when the images are "TRANSLUCENT".

So, I did some testing with fillRect instead of drawImage and I got the same behavior when the color has an alpha value.

**Here the example code:** (just an example code to demonstrate the performance difference)

```
  private final GraphicsConfiguration graphicsConfiguration = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice()
  .getDefaultConfiguration();

  // ...

  protected void paintComponent(final Graphics graphics) {
  super.paintComponent(graphics);

  final BufferedImage buffer = this.graphicsConfiguration.createCompatibleImage(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), Transparency.TRANSLUCENT);
  final Graphics2D bufferGraphics = (Graphics2D) buffer.getGraphics();

  bufferGraphics.setColor(new Color(110, 110, 110));

  for (int dy = 0; dy <= super.getHeight(); dy++) {
    for (short dx = 0; dx <= super.getWidth(); dx++) {        
      bufferGraphics.fillRect(dx, dy, 1, 1);
    }
  }
  graphics.drawImage(buffer, 0, 0, null);
}
```

The performance becomes worse (around 30 times slower) when "bufferGraphics.setColor(new Color(110, 110, 110));" is replaced by "bufferGraphics.setColor(new Color(110, 110, 110, 110));"

**Question:** Does anyone have an idea how to improve the performance?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The reason drawing with alpha (translucency) is slower than drawing with opaque colors, is because you suddenly have to deal with what was in the buffer already. For each pixel, you have to read it, compose with the new color using the current alpha composite rule, and then write it. With an opaque color, you can just write the new pixel value. PS: I'm not saying this can't be optimized, just that translucency will always be slower.

Comment: Do not forget after `getGraphics()` or `createGraphics()` to call at the end `graphics.dispose()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, draw directly on the `graphics` passed to your `paintComponent()`. Why do you create a buffered image, draw on it then copy/paint the whole image on the `graphics` (and then discard the buffered image)?

Swing is already double-buffered (by default): drawing on the passed `graphics` already happens on a buffer which will be made visible at the end of painting process of the `JComponent`. So your attempt to double-buffer is completely unnecessary and redundant.

If for some unknown reason you really need this, you should cache the created `BufferedImage` and reuse it in subsequent `paintComponent()` calls. Swing is single threaded, you don't even have to synchronize it or worry about concurrent access.

Comment: Drawing (semi-) transparent stuff usually is more expensive, because the system has to *check* what color already *is* at the target location and mix it with the new color, and can *not* just overwrite it as it could be done with non-transparent data. But +1: Creating a new image is not necessary here (and if it was required, it could be cached)

Comment: I create a buffered image in order to support the "double buffered" feature. I found this in a book abount swing (cannot remember the name). BTW: I tested it with direct drawing on the graphics improved the performance a lot).

Comment: @user3615209 Swing is already double-buffered (by default): drawing on the passed `graphics` already happens on a buffer which will be made visible at the end of painting process of the `JComponent`. So your attempt to double-buffer is completely unnecessary and redundant.

Comment: @user3615209 If the answer was helpful, you should not (or at least, not *only*) write a comment saying "Thanks". Instead, you should upvote the answer (and possibly accept it, if it completely solved your issue)

Comment: Does anyone knows if filling rectangle with fully transparent color (alpha = 0) creates a performance hit? Or is it optimized and skipped entirely?

Answer (score 0):

As far as tested on Java 13, raw bytewise operation for alphablending on image data array, written from scratch, are faster than calling awt primitives, especially if you have determined considerations on image data format and drawing operations. You can access buffered image pixels directly like this:

```
    image = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    data = ((DataBufferInt) mage.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
```

For example, this technique to logarithmically fade is about 3 times faster than fillrect with 50% alpha:

```
public void shift(int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1, int shift) {
    int channelMask    = 0xff & (~(0xFF << (8 - shift)));
    int mask = (channelMask << 16) | (channelMask << 8) | (channelMask);

    for (int i = y0; i < y1; i++) {
        for (int x = i * w + x0; x < i * w + x1; x++)
             data[x] = (data[x] >> shift) & mask;

    }
}
```